# "The more chickens in a farm the more crap and the fewer eggs"

Tags: phrase-requests, proverbs

Consider:

> The more chickens in a farm the more crap and the fewer eggs.

This is a proverb I hear often in Spanish (Cuba). I think it is pretty much self-explained: it is related to productivity and the negative effect of a workplace/task with too many people.

Is there a similar phrase in English? I googled this one and got nothing.

Comment: It's codified in _the law of diminishing returns_.

Comment: I'm curious. Is the proverb "The more hens...," "The more roosters...," or is the gender of the flock automatically male because of the presence of a single rooster?

Comment: In spanish the masculine plural includes both genders (although in some contexts it is considered of good manners to specify both). I like the shorter way, is nicer `The Kingdom of Men` than `The Kingdom of Men and Women`, so chickens in this case would be both, is just a parabole for people working.

Comment: Actually this case is one of the few exceptions to the male gender rule, `gallinas` (chickens) is the feminine, and includes boths. The male (rooster) is `gallo`. The original proverb in spanish is `A más gallinas en la granja más porquería y menos huevos`

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: It's nothing really to do with the Law of Diminishing Returns. That deals with the idea that as you saturate a market, only the people who said no before are left to sell to. This suggests a relative decrease in productivity caused by overloading a resource.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's ***Too many cooks spoil the broth***.

Everyone has a hand in the pot, so to speak, and what comes out is inedible.

Comment: Plus, nobody wants to eat boiled hand soup.

Answer (score 4):

A [Chinese proverb at thinkexist](http://thinkexist.com/quotation/an_overcrowded_chicken_farm_produce_fewer_eggs/255491.html) probably comes closest to the intended meaning:

> An overcrowded chicken farm produces fewer eggs.

In English, the word “chicken” has no gender attached. Per  [spanishdict.com](http://www.spanishdict.com/translate/chicken), in Spanish we have  “gallina (f) (bird); pollo (m) (meat)”.  A  *gallina* translation like “The more hens, the fewer eggs” would be parallel to the Chinese proverb. “The more roosters, the more crap and the fewer eggs” has a chance of being true if roosters crowd out hens.  (Roosters don't lay eggs.)

Another saying like *[Too many cooks spoil the broth](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Too+Many+Cooks+Spoil+the+Broth)* is *[Too many chiefs and not enough Indians](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/too+many+chiefs+and+not+enough+indians.html)*.  This also might apply if  roosters have crowded out hens.

Comment: Had no idea `chicken` was genderless, in spanish we put gender to everything, even inanimated objects. The `too many chiefs` is also perfect for many cases.

Comment: @xr09  Gendered terms are hen/pullet for a female, and rooster/cock for the male.  The latter usage of cock is relatively uncommon.

Comment: @xr09: Either too many "chiefs", or too many "chefs" – it seems like the same negative effect happens for both. :^)

Comment: I'd be careful about saying, "too many chiefs and not enough Indians". It is possible that you would hurt the feelings of the person you are talking to. It is likely that you would damage your own reputation.